# Can we re-run recorded Test script in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I create Test script using Thread Group,HTTP request, Recording Controller HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder and View result Tree, all data are record, now I want to rerun this script in Jmeter, so how can I rerun this script in Jmeter?

Please let me know if anyone have an idea about it or anyone can teach me about Jmeter.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) by choosing `Run -> Start` from JMeter's main menu:

[image]

Each [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler execution results will be added to the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

See [Building a Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual for the next steps.

Also if you're new to JMeter you can consider attending free [JMeter University](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/)

Comment: Okay let me check and Thank you for the replay